# How to send signal to program run in a docker container?

Tags: linux, signals, docker

I have a program run in a docker container with detached mode.

So how to send a signal such as SIGINT to this program?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use nsenter to get into your container space and send your signal.

```
PID=$(docker inspect --format {{.State.Pid}} <container_name_or_ID>)
nsenter --target $PID --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid kill -SIGINT <PID of your program inside your container>
```

More info : http://jpetazzo.github.io/2014/06/23/docker-ssh-considered-evil/

Comment: You can now use `docker exec` instead of nsenter. https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/exec/

Comment: New link for `docker exec`: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 103):

You can use `docker kill --signal="<signal>" <container name or id>` to send any signal to the root process of a given container.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/#send-a-custom-signal--to-a-container

Comment: Yeah，but the program I want to send signal to is a program run in the container but not have to the root process. e.g. run a bash in a docker, then run a other command in the bash in docker. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's what this does. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/kill/

Answer (score 9):

- `docker kill` used to send signal to main container process i.e process with PID 1.
- Any application with PID 1 can handle signals directly. Below command kill the main docker process: `$ docker kill --signal="SIGTERM" container-id/name`
- But application which does not have PID 1 i.e application is background process:

  - We can not send single directly to any background process running within docker container.
  - In this case we need to trap and handle the user defined signal in the shell script running as entry point.
- Let's we have the following `Dockerfile`. (Update it as per the application)

---

```
FROM centos:6.7
# Install/Deploye the service below.

# Copy the shell script.
COPY entrypoint.sh /home
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/entrypoint.sh"]
```

---

- Below is the `entrypoint.sh`. (Update it it as per the application). Suppose we wants to restart a `init.d` service.

  ```
  #start the service
  /etc/init.d/<servicename> start
  pid="$!"

  # SIGUSR1- Single handler
  my_handler() {
      /etc/init.d/<servicename> restart
  }

  # Trap and handle the user defind singnal.
  trap 'my_handler' SIGUSR1

  # wait forever(Alive container.)
  while true
  do
      tail -f /dev/null & wait ${!}
  done
  ```
- Build the docker image and run the container.
- Now you can restart the service from Host machine: `$docker kill --signal="SIGUSR1" container-id/name`

Comment: If someone is looking for more explanation and complete code: https://medium.com/@gchudnov/trapping-signals-in-docker-containers-7a57fdda7d86

Answer (score 4):

I managed to send a signal I want to a process(program) in docker container by:

1. Getting the ID of the container - **docker ps | grep yourProgramName** - for me it looks like so - 4b6425cf4261
2. Login into the container using **docker exec -it 4b6425cf4261 bash**
3. List all the running processes with **ps -A**
4. Find the **PID** of the process you want to send a SIGINT to
5. Send the signal to it: kill -SIGINT **PID** (example: kill -SIGINT 15)